# D3: only sorted data is logged to console (can't log raw data immediately after ingesting)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a csv file named `text.csv` that contains the following:

```
shape,color,distance
circle,blue,4
square,red,2
circle,blue,7
circle,green,9
triangle,blue,1
square,green,3
octagon,blue,4
```

I want to do the following:

1. load this data
2. log the loaded data to the console
3. sort the loaded data by `distance`
4. log the sorted data

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

d3.csv('test.csv', d3.autoType).then(function(data) {
    // INSPECTS THE RAW DATA
    console.log(data);

    // SORTS BY DISTANCE
    let sortedData = data.sort(function (a, b) {
        return d3.descending(a.distance, b.distance);
    })
    // LOGS SORTED DATA
    console.log(sortedData);
})
```

In the console, I see that sortedData is ***logged twice***.

The `data` variable (i.e. the raw unsorted data) is not being logged.

Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts the array **in place**. Also, your `sortedData` simply points to `data`.

Therefore, if you want to keep two arrays (the original and the sorted one), you have to duplicate it, for instance using [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone):

```js
const csv = `shape,color,distance
circle,blue,4
square,red,2
circle,blue,7
circle,green,9
triangle,blue,1
square,green,3
octagon,blue,4`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, d3.autoType);
console.log(data);

// SORTS BY DISTANCE
let sortedData = structuredClone(data).sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.descending(a.distance, b.distance);
})
// LOGS SORTED DATA
console.log(sortedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```